# Method inside Object undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm still learning how to use Javascript properly and have got stuck trying to set an interval on a function which is inside an object.

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/hJAtaqKi

On line 36 I am calling the function which is further down the page.. this works fine and references the function correctly.. but when I try to wrap that function in a setinterval setInterval('homePageFunctionality.animateCarousel($pause)', 4000);

It does not seem to work.. I get a homePageFunctionality is not defined..

Any idea why I cannot seem to reference the function when using setInterval?

Any other general feedback on my code is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass strings to `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. If you do, the parser has to `eval` them to turn them in to code, and it does that inside its own execution context so your variables aren't available.

Instead pass an anonymous function which does the same thing to `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    homePageFunctionality.animateCarousel($pause);
}, 4000);
```

Comment: +1, though this does not do the same thing, you just said that yourself. ;)

Comment: @Shaz What I meant to indicate was that the code does the same thing, but it only has the variables available when it's called in this way

Comment: I have a pause button I would like to hook up to it.. If I used the clearInterval() method it does not work. I'm guessing this would be because It is outside the function where the setInterval was called.. The onClick handler is inside the animateCarousel function and not the init function where the setInterval is "set"

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
 homePageFunctionality.animateCarousel($pause);
}, 4000);
```

try this.